# Is「酷い捨てられ方をされた」grammatical?

Tags: grammar

I recently encountered this expression「酷い捨てられ方をされた」from sentences below

> 色々調べたら貴方に酷い捨てられ方されたって人がわんさか証言をくれました。(Kaguya-sama 257)

> 酷い捨てられ方をされたけど ([source](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q11149246356))

Judging from context, I believe it means "got abandoned in cruel way" but I wonder if「酷い捨てられ方をされた」is grammatically correct. The usage of two passive verbs (捨てられる and される) is odd to me. I think the correct version would be either「酷い捨てられ方をした」or「酷い捨て方をされた」.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following mean all the same to me, but the bold された strongly suggests 被害/迷惑の受け身, so that 2 and 3 sound more like the speaker thinking she is damaged by being abandoned while 1 more neutrally states she was abandoned and that in a bad way. But these are a bit 'theoretical', I don't think they are really distinguished consciously.

1. 彼女はひどい捨てられ方をした
2. 彼女はひどい捨てられ方を**された**
3. 彼女はひどい捨て方を**された**

Note: 彼女はひどい捨て方をした means *she* is the one who abandoned.

Grammatically, one thing I noticed in a dictionary is that [方](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E6%96%B9_%28%E3%81%8B%E3%81%9F%29/#jn-41597) can mean

- ２ 動詞の連用形や動作性の漢語名詞に付いて、…すること、の意を表す。「打ち―やめ」「調査―を依頼される」

The 方 retains some meaning of *way*, but here it functions more as a nominalizer, so the above are roughly the same as the following (unnatural) sentences

1. 彼女はひどく捨てられることをした
2. 彼女はひどく捨てられることをされた
3. 彼女はひどく捨てることをされた

which roughly correspond to

1. She did (went through) the experience of being abandoned in a horrible way.
2. The experience of being abandoned in a horrible way was done to her.
3. She was done (a victim of) the act of abandoning in a horrible way.

---

I think ultimately all these work somehow by vagueness of 方（こと）・する.

Another thing to consider is the fact that generally there is no straightforward translation for *in adj. way*.

For example, it is not possible to translate *he abandoned her in a cruel way* into かれはadjなやりかたで/advで彼女を捨てた. 残酷に won't sound idiomatic here. (I mean this only generally. In specific cases, there could be straightforward translations. E.g. in a simple way = 単純に).

Answer (score 2):

I'm Japanese and your question is so cool and many Japanese people don't think like you.

I think if Japanese people see only 酷い捨てられ方をされた then don't think it's weird and they think like you "got abandoned in cruel way" .
When I read your question and I thought 酷い捨て方をされた is grammaticaly perfect but 酷い捨てられ方をした is weirder than  酷い捨てられ方をされた.
I'm not Japanese grammatical professional but according to my life in Japan for more than 35 years 酷い捨てられ方をされた is natural and no problem when you use in polite or casual situation.

Comment: Interesting! So using 捨てられ方 rather than 捨て方 will sound like speaker is deeply affected by the action of 捨てる?

Answer (score 0):

I think we don't say 捨て方をされた and rather say 捨てられ方をされた. This way you are stressing that it's got abandoned terribly, and also both 捨てられ and された are passive voice which is making it more sound like so.