# How to understand 取り上げ方をされており in a sentence

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

> 話し言葉によく現れる「なんか」は、日本語教育では中級以上の学生を対象としたテキストの会話文で取りあげられていることが多く、 「なんか」という語は辞書、**文法書によって様々な取り上げ方をされており**、その用法については「など」の口頭語として説明されたり、 「など」と同様に扱われているのが普通である。
> Often occurring in spoken language, the word なんか is often featured in the conversational sentences of textbooks aimed at intermediate level Japanese speakers. The word なんか is *picked up on in a variety of ways* by dictionaries and grammar books, and its usage is explained as a spoken version of など and is usually treated in the same way as など. (my translation attempt)

I'm stuck on the part in bold. I'm not at all sure how to translate 取り上げ方. I familiar with adding 方 to the masu-stem of a verb to mean 'way to verb', but I can't make much sense of this case.

More confusingly is what されており is doing and why it is in passive form but taking an object. Again, I'm familiar(-ish) with the so-called suffering passive but can't see why it would be used here.

I've looked at [this post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/93816/is-%E9%85%B7%E3%81%84%E6%8D%A8%E3%81%A6%E3%82%89%E3%82%8C%E6%96%B9%E3%82%92%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%9F-grammatical), which I think may be related, but I'm afraid it's not really helping me.

Comment: Regarding 取り上げ方, I understand it as "a way to deal/handle." Does it make sense to you?

Comment: @JimmyYang Thanks. Not a translation I've seen before, but it seems like it would be appropriate in this context.  Sadly, it doesn't help me untangle the rest of it.

Comment: This is funny, I understand intuitively what this part of sentence means but I have no idea how to put it into natural English...

Comment: See also the various glosses for 取り上げる [here at Eijirō](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E5%8F%96%E3%82%8A%E4%B8%8A%E3%81%92%E3%82%8B). One or more of these might spark an idea for you.

Comment: @aguijonazo "depending on" の方にしてみました

Answer (score 3, accepted):

取り上げる means "to bring up and/or discuss (a topic)". Sometimes it is used only in the sense of "to discuss".

Regarding this passive voice, there may be something irregular happening because この語**を**様々な取り上げ方**を**する sounds unnatural if not terrible. I feel no sense of 迷惑 in your sentence. Maybe we need to handle this as a special construction?

- この漢字は様々な書かれ方をする。
  この漢字は様々な書き方をされる。
  This kanji is written in various ways.
- 妙な褒められ方をした。
  妙な褒め方をされた。
  I was complimented in a strange manner.
- 色んな評価のされ方をする作品
  色んな評価のし方をされる作品
  a work appreciated in many ways

> 「なんか」という語は辞書、文法書によって様々な取り上げ方をされており、
> The word なんか is discussed in a variety of ways depending on the dictionary/grammar book, (and...)

Comment: I notice you just changed 'by' to 'depending on'. The original made more sense to me. The new sentence sounds a little off. If it was "depending on **the** (particular) dictionary/ grammar book "then that would make sense. Is there a good reason to choose one over the other?

Comment: @user3856370 Well, that's simply due to my poor English; I thought `the` is usually necessary after `depending on`, but noticed that's [not always the case](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=depending+on).

Comment: Poor English? Ha Ha, I wish my Japanese was that poor. But is the sentence actually ambiguous? Can によって mean both 'by' and 'depending on' in this case? What made you change your mind?

Comment: @user3856370 My first intuition was "depending on" (and perhaps aguijonazo thought so, too). I didn't use it since I was unsure how to use it properly in this context (especially concerning articles).